# Accessing controls that were moved

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am returning to coding after a long hiatus, and have come across a tiny issue that has me baffled. What I'm trying to do is simple, and it worked perfectly until I copied the controls from the winform and placed them in a tab control.

Very simply, I have a yes/no combobox with a conditional statement making a date time picker visible if the combobox is set to "Yes".  Since moving the controls into a tabcontrol (The project had so many controls, I had to condense them for space).  What's really crazy is I have a subroutine that resets all the controls in the project, and it still works.

when it worked, it looked like this:

```
If cmbAssessment.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
        dtpAssessment.Visible = True
End if
```

(TabControl is named tcNursing and form is frmNursing)

I just can't figure out how to reference these controls inside the Tab Control.

It seems like solutions from Googling the issue are very complex.  I'm finding it hard to believe this is 
a complex problem.  Thank you  for ANY assistance at all!

Comment: Did you copy or move these controls? Controls added a design-time are Fields declared in the parent Form class: you can access them directly no matter what container hosts them. If you copied these Controls (or part of them), then their names have been changed. So, the `SelectedIndexChanged` event is no longer subscribed to.

Comment: By their names? Unless the controls have been renamed due to _copying_ and not _moving_ them. Your code should work as usual if everything stills in the same context.

Comment: Thanks!  I actually cut and pasted them.  Their names are still the same.  Really bizarre.

Comment: See that the event handlers are still there and subscribed to.

Comment: Everything looks good.  I deleted all the controls, added new ones, and that particular function still doesn't work.  Unfortunately I'm probably going to have to start over...

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, Jimi, you were on the right track.  There was nothing obviously wrong with the event handlers, although deleting them and re-adding them solved the problem.  Thank you all for your help in this matter!